# How to customize webdriver entered URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver

I am new to using WebDriver and I need help with entering a URL.

I want to enter a customized URL like this "https/IP_adress"

```
try:
    driver.get(f'http://{ip_of_the_tested_device}')
except TimeoutException:
    print("couldn't get url")
```

but I am got error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "besma_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get(f'http://{ip}')
NameError: name 'ip' is not defined".
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below, I have used some random IP for the sake of example:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

ip_of_the_tested_device = "157.240.19.35"
try:
    driver.get(f'http://{ip_of_the_tested_device}')
    print(driver.title)
    time.sleep(15)
except TimeoutException:
    print("couldn't get url")
```

**Console output:**

```
Privacy error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [**Formatted string literals**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)

[PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) introduced a new string formatting mechanism known as *Literal String Interpolation* commonly known as [*f-strings*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/). Formatted string literals are prefixed with `f` and are similar to the format strings accepted by `str.format()`. They contain replacement fields surrounded by curly braces. The replacement fields are expressions, which are evaluated at run time, and then formatted using the `format()` protocol.

---

### This usecase

In your usecase you have used `f'http://{ip_of_the_tested_device}'` where *`ip_of_the_tested_device`* is a expression replaced at runtime. You need to have *`ip_of_the_tested_device`* defined earlier in your code as follows:

```
ip_of_the_tested_device = '192.169.18.19'

# lines of code

try:
    driver.get(f"http://{ip_of_the_tested_device}")
except TimeoutException:
        print("couldn't get url")
```